# iOS5 Assign a .xib to a custom UIView class

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uiview

HI have a custom view class that is loaded and placed within my main view using the following code. The reason it that i want to populate it with different content so rather than build a view in code each time if I create a custom class i can reuse this in a loop etc, I got this to work just fine in code, that is laying out the buttons label etc.

But rather than hand code it all I thought if i create a new User Interface View, then construct visually my text fields, labels  and buttons on this view.

Then connect it to my custom class.

Bu this is where I am having an issue, how do I connect this view xib file so that it becomes visible when placed on my my code.  I have assigned the custom class attribute within the xib file to my custom file, but what else am i missing?

.h File:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface blogView : UIView

 @end
```

.m File:

```
 #import "blogView.h"

 @implementation blogView

 - (id)init
 {
     self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 478, 220)];
     if (self != nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"Blog View loaded");

         self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

         UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 400, 40)];
         [titleLbl setText:@"This is the Title"];

         [self addSubview:titleLbl];

     }
     return self;
 }

 @end
```

my xib file has the same name blogView.xib which is a View User Interface.

Within my main view controller and in the ViewDidLoad i have

```
  blogView *blogItem = [[blogView alloc]init];
  [self.view addSubview:blogItem];
```

When I run this is all works fine, but I would like to link to a .xib file to save time etc.
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well having look around and trying bits of clues and suggestion I managed to do this with the following:

Within my .m file I placed/Changed the following:

```
  self = [super init];
  if (self != nil)
      {      
          NSArray *theView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"blogView" owner:self options:nil];
          UIView *nv = [theView objectAtIndex:0];

    .. rest of code.

   [self addSubview:nv];

 .. rest of code.
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Hm I couldn't get it to work within the init, instead it appears to work if you put it in the drawRect:

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *theView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RatingPickerView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *nv = [theView objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addSubview:nv];
}

Comment: But then how do you make a controller for it, and how would you reference the controller from the containing view's controller?

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for an hour when I RENAMED my viewcontroller class.  This is what worked for me in Xcode 5

1. Go to your XIB file
2. Click on Files owner transparent box on the left
3. Open up your inspections tab(Third button on right in the View Section - in between Editor and Organizer)
4. Go to your identity Inspector(3rd from the left) underneath the editor organizer view tab.
5. Fix the custom class  - Class option to whatever class you want it to respond to.

Lets just say I was extremely annoyed after wasting time with that

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a controller for your view and load that view using [initWithNibName:bundle:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion tried this for ages before posting but just could not get this to work, kept crashing.